# git share repository on ubuntu server over ssh to everyone

Tags: git, svn

I initially had an svn repository on my ubuntu server. I have now converted that into a git repository using git svn. I now have a .git directory under ~/csmart/git/csmart.

I would like all my colleagues now to start cloning this remote repository as their base and then start working on it. So effectively they would have all switched from svn on to git.

Now the question is how do I share that remote repository with everyone.

Things I tried:

1.
On the directory  ~/csmart/git/csmart I added a remote with the following command:

```
git remote add csmart ssh://csmartserver/~/csmart/git/csmart/csmart.git
```

On my local computer I tried to clone the repository with url:

```
git clone ssh://csmartserver/~/csmart/git/csmart/csmart.git
```

I get an error saying ~/csmart/git/csmart/csmart.git is not a git repository

2.
I tried to create a bare repository on another directory on the server. I then tried to push the repo under home/sethu/csmart/git/csmart/csmart.git to there ...

```
sethu@csmartserver:/data/csmart/git-repositories/csmart$ git --bare init
sethu@csmartserver:~/csmart/git/csmart$ git remote add origin ssh://localhost/data/csmart/git-repositories/csmart
sethu@csmartserver:~/csmart/git/csmart$ git push origin master
sethu@localhost's password: 
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://localhost/data/csmart/git-repositories/csmart'
```

My idea was to create the bare repository and share the git repo using that and discard the ~/csmart/git/csmart repo. But I was getting errors as show above. It says the master does not match. That kinda of makes sense. Does creating a bare repository create a branch with an alias master?

How do I share the git repo that I have created using svn.

Answer (score 0):

First, do try gitolite as it will take care of administering lots of users easily.

Make sure that you have ssh connections enabled in Ubuntu - it's not possible with a default install. Next, ensure that you have the proper file and folder permissions.